# How to get input radio name with many different name in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

In this project, i make something like online test. my question is how to get radio name with many different name in laravel ? i use id to different their name so but i cant get their name in controller.

this is my view

```
<form action="{{url('kumpulkan')}}" method="POST" class="responsive-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            @if(Session::get('jurusan') == Multimedia)
                <?php 
                    $no = 1;
                 ;?>
                @foreach($soal_multimedia as $row)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="wrapper-soal">
                            <div class="pertanyaan">
                                <span class="no-soal"><?php echo $no++ ;?>. </span> <span class="teks-soal">{{$row->soal}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jawaban">
                                <input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="id_soal" value="{{$row->id}}" hidden="hidden">
                                <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-a">
                                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban_{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->jawaban_a}}"> {{$row->jawaban_a}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-b">
                                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban_{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->jawaban_b}}"> {{$row->jawaban_b}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-c">
                                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban_{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->jawaban_c}}"> {{$row->jawaban_c}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-d">
                                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban_{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->jawaban_d}}"> {{$row->jawaban_d}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>                      
                @endforeach
            @endif
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Selesai</button>
            </form>
```

this is my controller

```
    public function Postkumpulkan(Request $request)
{
    $insert = array();
    $insert['id_soal']    = $request->get('id_soal');
    $insert['nama']       = Session::get('nama');
    $insert['no_peserta'] = Session::get('no_peserta');
    $insert['sekolah']    = Session::get('sekolah');
    $insert['jurusan']    = Session::get('');
    $insert['jawaban']    = $request->get('jawaban_{{$row->id}}');

}
```

Comment: Where does `$row` come from in your controller?

Comment: from my view in input radio name = "jawaban_{{$row->id}}", i think that how to get the name

Answer (score 1):

i think you would better use checkbox and instead of this naming `jawaban_{{$row->id}}`

use this kind `jawaban[{{$row->id}}]` in this case you can get all jawabans in one array

like this :

```
$insert['jawaban'] = $request->get('jawaban');
```

Comment: in this case, the user only can choose 1 option in every question, so i choose radio

Comment: thanks for your answer, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you intend to make your radio buttons to work as a radiogroup (yes, where you can only choose 1) and since that is how radio buttons work, you should just give the same name for all the radio buttons.

```
<div class="jawaban">
    <input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="id_soal" value="{{$row->id}}" hidden="hidden">
    <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-a">
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban" value="{{$row->jawaban_a}}"> {{$row->jawaban_a}}
    </div>
    <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-b">
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban" value="{{$row->jawaban_b}}"> {{$row->jawaban_b}}
    </div>
    <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-c">
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban" value="{{$row->jawaban_c}}"> {{$row->jawaban_c}}
    </div>
    <div class="jawaban-item jawaban-d">
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban" value="{{$row->jawaban_d}}"> {{$row->jawaban_d}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can just retrieve it in the controller:

```
 $insert['jawaban'] = $request->get('jawaban');
```

It will retrieve the chosen radio button.

Comment: the problem is, isnt just a single data, it is multiple data so i must different their name. so i use id to different their name

Comment: if i naming the radio with the same name, it just select 1 data. and the rest will not be inputed

Comment: then don't use radio box, use checkbox and do the same. it will return an array in your controller in that case

Comment: nevermind, i use foreach to get the array data, thanks for your helps